# Check if an element in the x position of an array is equal to something

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, loops

I'm trying to create a method that takes a string as input, and if the string contains `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, `five`, `six`, `seven`, `eight`, or `nine`, counts them as integers and adds them, for example:

```
secret_code("one on one") #=> 2
secret_code("five monkeys in three farms") #=> 8
secret_code("") #=> 0
secret_code("fivethreeone") #=> 0
```

I wanted to split the given string by words and put them into an array so that I could iterate it and check if the element at position `i` equals to a number, and add its corresponding value to a variable. This is my code so far:

```
def secret_code(a)
  arr = a.split(/\W+/)
  i = 0
  l = arr.size
  num = 0
  puts arr
  if !arr.any?
    0
  end
  while i < l do 
    case arr
      when arr[i] == "one"
        num += 1
        exit
      when arr[i] == "two"
        num += 2
        exit
      when arr[i] == "three"
        num += 3
        exit
      when arr[i] == "four"
        num += 4
        exit
      when arr[i] == "five"
        num += 5
        exit
      when arr[i] == "six"
        num += 6
        exit
      when arr[i] == "seven"
        num += 7
        exit
      when arr[i] == "eight"
        num += 8
        exit
      when arr[i] == "nine"
        num += 9
        exit
    end
    i+=1
  end
  puts num
end

secret_code("one on one") #=> 2
secret_code("five monkeys in three farms") #=> 8
secret_code("") #=> 0
secret_code("fivethreeone") #=> 0
```

I'm not quite sure how to iterate over the array. Right now it prints `0` for everything.

Comment: Your `case` statement seems to have some flaws - have a look at this - [How to write case statement in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby) - and don't use `exit` - it will exit from program prematurely.  If you fix your `case` and get rid of `exit`, you will correct output

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You may discourage other interesting answers by doing so, and imo it is inconsiderate to readers still working on their answers when you made the selection. Many SO members wait at least a couple of hours--sometimes much longer--before making a selection.

Comment: Many wait a couple days. Good answers take a while to create, plus people who answer are spread across the globe, or only get on Stack Overflow every few days.

Comment: The basic problem is answered in the duplicated question's selected answer. The rest of this problem is how to match words to decide what is a "number word" and what isn't, and that's easily done with a hash or array of acceptable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
NUMBERS = {
  'one'   => 1, 'two'   => 2, 'three' => 3,
  'four'  => 4, 'five'  => 5, 'six'   => 6,
  'seven' => 7, 'eight' => 8, 'nine'  => 9
}

def secret_code(string)
  words = string.split(/\W+/)

  words.inject(0) do |sum, word|
    sum + NUMBERS.fetch(word, 0)
  end
end

puts secret_code('one on one')
#=> 2
puts secret_code('five monkeys in three farms')
#=> 8
puts secret_code('')
#=> 0
puts secret_code('fivethreeone')
#=> 0
```

[`NUMBERS.fetch(word, 0)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) tries to get a value from the `NUMBERS` hash, it returns `0` if the key `word` does not exist. It basically does the same than:

```
if NUMBERS.key?(word)
  0
else
  NUMBERS[word]
end
```

[`inject(0) do |sum, word|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is initialized with `0`. It iterates over each element in an array and passes the current value as `sum` to the block. The result of the block (`sum +` the value of the word) is used as new value of `sum` in the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
case arr
  when arr[i] == "one"
    num += 1
  # ...
end
```

In a `case` statement, the value you give after each `when` will be compared to the value you give after `case`. In other words, your `case` statement will first do `(arr[i] == "one") === arr`, then `(arr[i] == "two") === arr`, and so on. Since `arr[i] == "one"` returns `true` or `false`, and `true === arr` and `false === arr` will never be true, none of the conditions in your `case` statement are ever met.

The simplest fix is this:

```
case arr[i]
  when "one"
    num += 1
  when "two"
    num += 2
  when "three"
    num += 3
  # ...
end
```

What this code does is compare the value of `arr[i]` to `"one"`, then `"two"`, and so on, which yields the intended behavior.

Note also that I removed `exit`. In Ruby, `exit` exits the program. I'm guessing you were trying to use it like you'd use `break` in other programming languages. You don't need that here, because Ruby `case` statements don't have "fall-through" like `switch` does in some languages. Only one `when` will match in a `case` statement.

### More improvements

I have a few more notes on your code:

1. This code doesn't do anything:

   ```
   if !arr.any?
     0
   end
   ```

   You don't do anything with that `0`, so it just disappears into the void. You probably meant to do `return 0` to return from the method early. A better idiom would have been this:

   ```
   return 0 if arr.empty?
   ```
2. `while` is unnecessary here In Ruby it's much more common to use `Enumerable#each` to iterate over elements of an array:

   ```
   arr.each do |word|
     case word
       when "one"
         # ...
       # ...
     end
   end
   ```
3. You can make your `case` statement much more concise by treating it as an expression that returns a value:

   ```
   num += case arr[i]
     when "one"   then 1
     when "two"   then 2
     when "three" then 3
     # ...
     else 0
   end
   ```
4. You can make this more concise still by using a Hash instead of a `case` statement:

   ```
   word_values = {
     "one"   => 1, "two"   => 2, "three" => 3,
     "four"  => 4, "five"  => 5, "six"   => 6,
     "seven" => 7, "eight" => 8, "nine"  => 9
   }
   word_values.default = 0

   arr.each do |word|
     num += word_values[word]
   end
   ```

   This iterates over the array of words and looks up each one in the `word_values` hash. If the word isn't in the hash it will return the default value, `0`.
5. With the `word_values` hash you could also do the following:

   ```
   values = arr.map {|word| word_values[word] }
   puts values.reduce(:+)
   ```

   This uses `map` to transform the array of words into an array of values, for example `"five monkeys in three farms"` becomes `[5, 0, 0, 3, 0]`. It then uses `reduce` (also called `inject`) to calculate the sum of the values.

### All together now

Put all of those improvements together and we have this:

```
WORD_VALUES = {
  "one"   => 1, "two"   => 2, "three" => 3,
  "four"  => 4, "five"  => 5, "six"   => 6,
  "seven" => 7, "eight" => 8, "nine"  => 9
}
WORD_VALUES.default = 0

def secret_code(str)
  str.split(/\W+/)
    .map {|word| WORD_VALUES[word] }
    .reduce(:+) || 0
end

puts secret_code("one on one") # => 2
puts secret_code("five monkeys in three farms") # => 8
puts secret_code("") # => 0
puts secret_code("fivethreeone") # => 0
```

(In Ruby 2.3 you can actually do `.map(&WORD_VALUES)`, which is pretty neat.)

And here's another approach, which is slightly more efficient:

```
def secret_code(str)
  str.split(/\W+/).reduce(0) {|sum, word| sum + WORD_VALUES[word] }
end
```

It uses `reduce` in its block form to look up each value in the hash and add it to a running `sum`.

### An alternative

This is slightly more "advanced," but shows off some other Ruby features:

```
WORD_VALUES = {
  "one"   => 1, "two"   => 2, "three" => 3,
  "four"  => 4, "five"  => 5, "six"   => 6,
  "seven" => 7, "eight" => 8, "nine"  => 9
}

WORD_EXPR = /\b#{Regexp.union(WORD_VALUES.keys)}\b/

def secret_code(str)
  str.scan(WORD_EXPR).reduce(0) {|sum, word| sum + WORD_VALUES[word] }
end
```

This uses the keys of the `WORD_VALUES` array to build a regular expression that looks (more or less) like this:

```
WORD_EXPR = /\b(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)\b/
```

Then it uses `String#scan`, which returns all of the substrings that match the regular expression, so e.g. `"five monkeys in three farms".scan(WORD_EXPR)` returns `["five", "three"]`. Then it uses `reduce` as above to look up their values and sum them.

Answer (score 2):

Your case statement is wrong as it contains [`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) that in Ruby causes the immediate termination of the running script.

You should check the proper syntax of the case statement.

Moreover, you can use `scan` to quickly scan your string for matches.

```
"five monkeys in three farms".scan(/five|three|four/)
 => ["five", "three"]
```

And then you can convert the matches into the corresponding values (for example with a map stored in a Hash) and compute the result.

```
numbers = {
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4,
    "five" => 5,
}

results = "five monkeys in three farms".scan(/#{numbers.keys.join("|")}/)
 => ["five", "three"]

results.inject(0) { |total, result| total += numbers[result] }
# => 8
```

There is one caveat with this solution. It will match partial words, therefore you will need to adapt it to consider full words using the appropriate boundaries if it applies (hence if someone can send strings like the last one you provided in the example).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code has been answered by others. Here's an alternative.

```
str = "five monkeys in three farms"

h = { "one=>1", "two"=>2, "three"=>3, "four"=>4, "five"=>5,
      "six"=>6, "seven"=>7, "eight"=>8, "nine"=>9 }

str.gsub(/\w+/,h).split.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  #=> 8
```

This uses the form of [Hash.gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that employs a hash. The steps:

```
s = str.gsub(/\w+/,h)
  #=> "5   3 "
```

Matches that are not keys of `h` are converted to empty strings. Spaces do not match `\w+/` so they are unaffected.

```
t = s.split
  #=> ["5", "3"] 
u = t.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [5, 3] 
u.reduce(:+)
  #=> 8
```

Comment: That's not the easiest thing to puzzle out for a beginner. Could you add some explanation?

Comment: I agree it may be hard to read for a beginner and it would be helpful to elaborate it, but I'm voting +1 because it's a pretty clever and nice implementation. It's important to note that, however, it doesn't really answer why the user is experiencing the problem with his code. ;)

Comment: I always try to provide explanations, but sometimes, as here, I present the code alone and then edit to provide the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are many [functions to search strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html) in Ruby. You don't have to do it manually and its rare you'd want to. For this you'd use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan) to find words.

```
str.scan(/(\w+)/) { |word|
    ... do something with word[0] ...
}
```

Then you need to turn those words into numbers.  There's several ways to do it provided in "[Convert string numbers( in word format) to integer ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564680/convert-string-numbers-in-word-format-to-integer-ruby)".  For production code you should [use a gem](https://github.com/markburns/numbers_in_words), but since this is an exercise in scanning strings the simplest is to use a little table.

```
str = "one two five and zero"

# Map words to their numbers.
word2num = {
    "one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3, "four" => 4, "five" => 5,
    "six" => 6, "seven" => 7, "eight" => 8, "nine" => 9, "ten" => 10,
    "eleven" => 11, "twelve" => 12
};
# Because there are words which are not numbers, set the default
# for the hash to 0.  If you try to put in a word that's not a
# number you'll get 0 instead of nil (which would cause an error).
word2num.default = 0

number = 0;
str.scan(/(\w+)/) { |word|
    number += word2num[word[0]]
}
puts number
```

Comment: What if the string were `"eighteen monkeys"`, which should return zero?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Like I said, in real code you'd use a gem. This isn't about adding numbers, there's already a whole other question for that which I linked to, it's about teaching how to scan strings in Ruby.